# Application settings values are default when read from another project

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have 2 projects. I am trying to get some user-scoped application settings from project A and read them from project B. To do that I created the following class (in project A):

```
public class GeneralSettings
{
    public string strLogFilesPath {get; private set;}

    public GeneralSettings()
    {
        this.strLogFilesPath = GSN_PrestaBiz_UserUI_VS2013.Properties.Settings.Default.PathLogFiles;
    }
}
```

And I then instanciate the class from project B :

```
GSN_PrestaBiz_UserUI_VS2013.GeneralSettings ps = new GSN_PrestaBiz_UserUI_VS2013.GeneralSettings();
```

but for some reason I just get the default value of the type every time, in this case (string) it's "" and for booleans that I have in another similar class it's "false".

But I know those are not the values of the settings. I tried to instanciate that same class from Project A (the same project the settings belong to) and it worked, the values are correct and not just the default ones.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the location/file saved to is based on a hash of values for the app running, so one app cannot get settings for another unless you save them manually to a fixed location you control.  We *like* this otherwise saving settings from a DLL method would put them somewhere that the app itself could not get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term for "project" is actually **assembly** so I will use that when referring to "project".

The `ConfigurationManager` does not work the way you are trying to use it. The files are not hardcoded/locked to the particular assemblybut rather to the specific executable.config and user.config.

When retrieving settings from another assembly what the `ConfigurationManager` is really looking for is in the current execution context's user.config/exe.config file but under the namespace of the other assembly.

This is why when you look in one assembly's configuration using `ConfigurationManager` at runtime, the settings exist but in the other executable's runtime, they do not.

Comment: I see. So what should I do, read directly from the user.config file ?

Comment: You could. Or you could add the settings you require from the other assembly in the executable's app.config and user.config file under the appropriate namespace.

Comment: Additional explanation of what toadflakz is saying can be found in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817051/can-a-class-library-have-an-app-config-file