# EF - Code First approach: connection string and initializer are not being picked from app.config file

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, app-config, code-first

I have a class library project where I have created entities, and context for Entity Framework. I have also created an initializer to seed default data in the database.

Following is the app.config file of the class library project -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="WebExplore.Context.GeographyContext, WebExplore.Context">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebExplore.Context.WebExploreInitializer, WebExplore.Context" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebExploreEntities"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=WebExplore.Database;Integrated Security=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

However, when I try to create a database using "Update-Database", it does create a database with a default name, and without seed data.

I believe, somehow the app.config settings are not being picked when I try to create the database through "Update-Database" command.

Can anyone please help me creating database and seed data by taking app.config settings into an account?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an app.config to your class library project... *you can't* (see [Can a class library have an App.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817051/can-a-class-library-have-an-app-config-file)). You need to add the app/web.config file to a project that can be started (i.e. the actual application).

Comment: you mean, when we use code first approach, should we always write our DbContext in the actual application only? I guess, this is opposite to Database-first approach where we can just create the EDMX in the class library and the class library project then contains the connection details to enable updating entities from the database.

Comment: No, the DbContext lives in the Class Library, it's just the .config that lives with the actual application. You can use the same DbContext+ClassLibrary from multiple projects with different connection settings. This is very useful for things like unit testing.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point... yes, indeed, I just had to move the configurations in a project that can be started.. thanks