# App config in Class library C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application which is using a dll of a class library. I am unable to access the app.config value in the class library

How I'm trying to access app.config:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conStr"].ToString();
```

this is returning a null value
using System.Configuration is also added .

Comment: Is there any reason not to expose the relevant properties through a public class defined by the library?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put that value in the Main Project ?

If you're calling the class library from the Main Project. Then the code in the class library uses the AppConfig defined inside the main project.

It is a common practice to have the connection string in the AppConfig for the Main Project and not inside the Class Library.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to use your own class for save Class Library settings. Something like this:

```
public class GlobalSettings
{

    public double RedFiber { get; set; }
    public double GreenFiber { get; set; }
    public double BlueFiber { get; set; }
    public bool DeleteMinorViews { get; set; }


    public static GlobalSettings Load()
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlobalSettings>(File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\YOUR_APP_NAME\\"));
        }
        catch ()
        {
            return DefaultSettings;                
        }

    }

    public void Save()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\YOUR_APP_NAME\\", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented));
    }

    private static readonly GlobalSettings DefaultSettings = new GlobalSettings()
    {
        RedFiber = 0,
        GreenFiber = 255,
        BlueFiber = 0,
        DeleteMinorViews = true,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try adding a settings file for your class library to store your values. The value will be stored in the app.config but accessed using the settings file.

This post explains better: [Can a class library have an App.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817051/can-a-class-library-have-an-app-config-file)

This post goes into more detail about settings files: [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

If you prefer not to do the above you can also move your data to the main projects App.config file and it should work.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conStr"].ToString();
```

If the does not work post your App.Config

[ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is obsolete