# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-service-fabric

I am creating Service Fabric application, when i try to create service instance listeners i have this error:
[image]

Only place where I have System.Runtime is in one of class libraries that are used by my Service Fabric Microservice.

```
<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

There is nothing about System.Runtime in dependentAssembly in side of any App.config in my Solution.

Also I am confused why is error mentioning version 4.1.0.0 and version 4.0.0.0.

Comment: You need to make sure packages are in each project for reference, have you done this?

Comment: You are probably missing a [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) for version `4.0.0.0` in your app.config. You can debug this with [fusionlogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer). Also try clean and build.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I did add System.Runtime from Nuget in every of my projects if u asking that?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I tried adding dependentAssembly in app.config but still get same error.

Comment: @FilipFilipovic, please try to run  `gacutil /i System.Runtime.dll` of the nuget package `System.Runtime 4.1.0`. You can refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019110/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-buffers-version-4-0-2-0/63031245#63031245). Please let us know if it helps or not.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I tried that,  both solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe/62770487#62770487) and it didn`t work.