System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Buffers, or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
I have a .NET 4.8 Class Library in which I'm using Azure.Storage.Blobs nuget to upload files to Azure.
The connection to Azure establishes successfully, however I get an error before Fileupload -
blockBlobClient.Upload(uploadFileStream);
Error states that-
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Exception.GetStackTrace(Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
   at System.IO.FileNotFoundException.ToString()
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at AzureMain.AzureWrapper.UploadFileToAzure(String connectionString, String containerName, String blobName, String uploadFilePath) in D:\Azure new\AzureMain\AzureWrapper.cs:line 102
   at AzureMain.AzureWrapper.AzureInitialize(String connectionString, String containerName) in D:\Azure new\AzureMain\AzureWrapper.cs:line 46

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllhost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/SysWOW64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.17.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

The name of my DLL is AzureMain which is called from another DLL in same .net 4.8 framework named AzureWrapper.
I tried adding binding redirect to the app.config as-
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

However this did not work. Also, I checked the nuget System.Buffers, there is no publicly release version 4.0.2.0 for this nuget
Edit -
As mentioned in the comment about the similar question in -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019110/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-buffers-version-4-0-2-0
I have tried the accepted solution in it -

Cannot be done as there is no GAC at my runtime, as Visual Studio i not there at my runtime environment.
Updated the Version=4.0.2.0 to Version=4.0.3.0 in csproj file for System.Buffers. But this did not work.
I already have binding resirects in my app.config. They are not working.
Tried downgrading the nuget for System.Buffers. However Visual Studio itself does not allow building project in this case at gives the following error-

Unable to resolve dependencies. 'System.Buffers 4.5.0' is not compatible with 'System.IO.Hashing 8.0.0 constraint: System.Buffers (>= 4.5.1)', 'System.Text.Encodings.Web 8.0.0 constraint: System.Buffers (>= 4.5.1)', 'System.Text.Json 8.0.4 constraint: System.Buffers (>= 4.5.1)'.
Please suggest some solution if someone knows.

This question is similar to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0...'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have edited and updated my question with the solution in that question. It did not work for me.

Make sure the binding redirect is in the app.config or web.config of the application project for the running application. In your case, this may be AzureWrapper, or perhaps another project that references AzureWrapper.

Yes, I tried this but still the issue persists..
Under configuration added this..

What type of application is it that is using the AzureMain and AzureWrapper dlls? It might set off a lightbulb if I could hear more about the runtime context. I did notice that your assembly binding log includes No application configuration file found.
